# How can I run my program without having to type ./?

Tags: bash, compiling

My teacher wants to be able to compile our programs without having to type ./.

For example we would write:

```
g++ some_program.cpp -o some_program
some_program
```

He says to type:

1. `cp .bash_profile .bash_profile.ORIG`
2. Then load `.bash_profile` into text editor
3. Then go to the end of the file `PATH=$Path:` and add a period
4. `export`
5. restart

My questions are:

1. Do I just type `cp .bash_profile .bash_profile.ORIG` into the terminal right after I open it?
2. How do I load it into my text editor?
3. And how do I export it?

Comment: Adding the current directory symbol '.' to your PATH is generally viewed as a security risk, (or at least an endlessly revisited discussion point).  (and your questions suggest that your teacher hasn't done wonders with other basic instructions)  Here is a closely similar discussion: http://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory

Comment: I would seriously recommend finding a better teacher given that he did not know how to source a file in the shell, thought adding the current directory to the path was a good idea, and has not taught you how to open an editor. Three strikes. Feel free to let him know I said this. If you had a competent  teacher you would not be asking these questions. I am not saying they are bad questions for a beginner, but your teacher should have already answered them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Do I just type cp .bash_profile .bash_profile.ORIG into the
>   terminal right after I open it?

Yes. You are essentially making a backup copy of your current `~/.bash_profile` (assuming there is one).

> 2) How do I load it into my text editor?

It depends on what text editor you intend to use. I do this:

```
$ emacs ~/.bash_profile
```

but you could also do:

```
$ gedit ~/.bash_profile
```

There are heaps of text editors, of course, including `nano` or `pico` for in-terminal editing. So really just take your pick. If you don't have a favourite editor, `nano` is a good starter.

#### Note:

The line should not be `PATH=$Path:`
It should be:

```
PATH="$PATH:."
```

As Theophrastus says in the comment, this is a horrible security practise and generally should not be done. I think it's better practise to designate a directory where you code, and a directory where executables get stashed for testing and that is in `$PATH`. But if this is a school assignment, I guess you should do as your teacher says.

> 3) And how do I export it?

Add this line after the `$PATH` line:

```
export PATH
```

Note: your teacher is wrong. You do not need to restart. How would that be possible if you were maintaining a server? you'd kick everyone off and your users would be furious! All you need to do to load in new settings is:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Good luck!

Comment: @ZachStow if his answer works for you, you should accept it so people like me don't come to answer it again.